# Copy Multiple Rows from MSSql Server to MySql

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, sql-server

I wanna copy a result from MSSql Server to MySql in one query

this below code Fitch for a SO_Numbber inside a MSSql View and get the results i'd like to copy this result all at once into another table on MySql

```
<form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" id="sales" method="post">
    <!-- text input -->
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>
            <input type="text" name="SO_Number"/>
        </label>
    </div>


    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="Submit" name="Submit" id="Submit">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
<?php 

    //connect to a DSN "myDSN" 
    $Connection = odbc_connect('SQL','sa','sa'); 

    if ($Connection) 
    { 

    if (isset($_POST['SO_Number']))             {$SO_Number = $_POST['SO_Number'];} 
    if (isset($_POST['Submit']))
        {  //the SQL statement that will query the database 
            $Query = "SELECT * FROM [test_eta].[dbo].[AAR1472] WHERE LPO_NO = $SO_Number"; 
            //perform the query 
            $Result=odbc_exec($Connection, $Query); 

            echo "<table border='1'><tr>"; 

            //print field name 
            $colName = odbc_num_fields($Result); 
            for ($j=1; $j<= $colName; $j++) 
            {  
              echo "<th>"; 
              echo odbc_field_name ($Result, $j ); 
              echo "</th>"; 
            } 

            //fetch tha data from the database 
            while(odbc_fetch_row($Result)) 
            { 
              echo "<tr>"; 
              for($i=1;$i<=odbc_num_fields($Result);$i++) 
              { 
                echo "<td>"; 
                echo odbc_result($Result,$i); 
                echo "</td>"; 
              } 
              echo "</tr>"; 
            } 

              echo "</td> </tr>"; 
              echo "</table >"; 

              //close the connection 
              odbc_close ($Connection); 
        }
    } 
    else echo "odbc not connected"; 
?>
```

Comment: Fine. And your question is?

Comment: @AjVJsy - Actually, PHP can evaluate variables in-line... which is dangerous when they come from user (untrusted) input.  He's vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) (your suggestion is as well).  As for the OP... why don't you export/import the rows in a bulk load?  Or link the servers?  In this case, you only have a connection to one db, where's the other one?  What is the problem in your code?